# Flutter Firebase_Auth upgrade breaks OTP Phone Authorization on iOS (All Versions)

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-authentication, one-time-password

Okay, so I'm building an iOS app in flutter, using firebase_auth, and was experiencing a small error.

Ordinarily with firebase_auth if you've already authorized on the device, it should just pass you through firebase_auth, and into the rest of the program.  My program did not do this.  It would ask for text message verification each and every time regardless.

So my first instinct as to how to resolve this issue was to verify if I was on the latest versions of firebase_auth, and other dependencies.  Verified there were some that were out of date, and so updated them.  (Going from 15.3 to 15.4 firebase_auth; along with firebase_core 4.3+1 - 4.4; and a few others that don't effect this)

The ONLY changes were to my pubspec.yaml, and all of a sudden, none of my code works anymore.  Firebase never sends a text.  Just incase it was actually completing the authorization in the background I added some more print statements, to know where in the code things are happening, but none of those messages get printed out.

I've tried testing this on both an iphone 11 pro max running ios 13.4 and an iphone 5e, running 13.3.1, and the same issue happens on both.

As this was due to the updates to the pubspec.yaml, I tried reverting those changes, (Thank you GitHub) but it hasn't effected the code, and firebase still never sends a text anymore to either phone, with no error message, or print message going to the debug screen.  And ideas?

Code as follows:

```
class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget { // Base Scaffold for Login Page
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new CupertinoPageScaffold(
      navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
        middle: Text('Verification'),
      ),
      child: new _PhoneLoginSection(),
    );
  }
}

class _PhoneLoginSection extends StatefulWidget{

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _PhoneLoginSectionState();
}

class _PhoneLoginSectionState extends State<_PhoneLoginSection>{

  final TextEditingController _phoneNumberController = TextEditingController();
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

//  Firebase Authorization request
  Future<void> verifyPhone(context) async {
    try {
      final credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
        verificationId: this.verificationId, 
        smsCode: this.smsCode, 
      );
      print('Already Authorized.');
      final FirebaseUser user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
      final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
      assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);
      IdTokenResult firebaseIdToken = await user.getIdToken(); 
      setInfo(this.phoneNumber, firebaseIdToken);  
      toMap(context);
    } catch (e) {
        print(e);
        catchError(e, context);
    }
  } // End of Authorization request


   // SMS Verification Screen Widget
    Future<bool> smsCodeDialog(BuildContext context) {    
        return showCupertinoDialog(    
            context: context,    
            builder: (BuildContext context) {    
                return new AlertDialog(    
                backgroundColor: currentTheme.primaryColor,  
                title: Text('Enter SMS Code', style: TextStyle(color: currentTheme.textTheme.textStyle.color),),    
                content: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, children: [
                  Divider(),    
                  CupertinoTextField(    
                      placeholder: '123456',
                      autofocus: true,                           
                      maxLength: 6,
                      maxLengthEnforced: true,
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      inputFormatters: [WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
                      onSubmitted: (value) {
                        verifySms(context, value); 
                      },  
                      controller: _phoneNumberController, 
                    ), 
                  Divider(),
                  (errorMessage != ''    
                      ? Text(    
                          errorMessage,    
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),    
                          )    
                      : Container())    
                ]),   
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(16),    
                actions: <Widget>[    
                    FlatButton(    
                    child: Text('Submit', 
                      style: TextStyle(color: currentTheme.textTheme.textStyle.color), ),    
                    onPressed: () {   
                        verifySms(context, _phoneNumberController.text); 
                    },    
                    )    
                ],    
                );    
        });    
    }
    // END of SMS Verification Screen Widget


// Method to call validation of phone number and credentials.
  void openCodePage(context) async {
    if (!debugging) {
      setState((){codeSent = true;});
      final PhoneCodeSent smsCodeSent = (verID, [int forceResendingToken]) async {
        this.verificationId = verID;
        smsCodeDialog(context).then((value) {});
      };

    // Complete Phone Authorization, and generate ID Token
      final PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationComplete = (AuthCredential credential) async {
      validationComplete = true;
      print('Authorized only through SMS.');
      _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
      FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
      IdTokenResult firebaseIdToken = await user.getIdToken(); 
      setInfo(this.phoneNumber, firebaseIdToken);  
      toMap(context);
    };

    // Error handling.  Method required for Firebase Phone Auth.
    final PhoneVerificationFailed verificationFailed = (AuthException exception) {
      print('Phone Auth Verification Failed: ${exception.message}');
      setState((){
        codeSent = false;
      });
    };
    // End of Error Handling

  // Automatically Sign-In after timeout.  Method required for Firebase Phone Auth.
  final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout timeout = (String verID) {
    setState((){
    });
  print('Code Auto Retreival Timed Out: ${this.verificationId}');
  };

  // Actual Authorization request.  Method required for Firebase Phone Auth.
  try {
      await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: this.phoneNumber, 
        timeout: const Duration(seconds: 20),
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: timeout,
        verificationCompleted: verificationComplete,
        verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
        codeSent: smsCodeSent,
      );
  } catch(e) {
    print('Verify Phone Number Error: $e');
  } 
    }
    else {
      toMap(context);
    }
  } // END openCodePage Function



// Error Handling Function for validation errors.  
  catchError(PlatformException error, context) {
    print(error);
    switch (error.code) {
      case 'ERROR_INVALID_VERIFICATION_CODE':
      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
      setState(() {
        errorMessage = 'Invalid Code';
      });
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
      smsCodeDialog(context).then((value) {

      });
      break;
      default:
      setState(() {
        errorMessage = error.message;
      });
      break;
    }
  }
  //End Error Handling Function

// User Phone Number Input Cleaning
void validatePhone(phoneNum){
  if (phoneNum.length < 10){
    return;
  } else if (phoneNum.length == 11) {
    this.phoneNumber = '+' + phoneNum;
    setNumber(phoneNum.substring(1));
  } else {
    this.phoneNumber = '+1' + phoneNum;
    setNumber(phoneNum);
  }
  _phoneNumberController.text = '';
}
// End User Phone Number Input Cleaning


// User SMS Input Cleaning
void verifySms(context, code) async {
  if (code.length < 6){
    return;
  }
  this.smsCode = code;
  verifyPhone(context);
}
// End SMS Input Cleaning


// Actual Transition Code.  Go to Map
void toMap(context){
  setHistoryList();
  Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
      CupertinoPageRoute(
        maintainState: false,
        fullscreenDialog: false,
        builder: (context) =>
          MainAppPage()),
        (Route<dynamic> route) => false
    );

  }  // End of Transition Code

// Build base context widget, and accept user input.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: const Text('Enter your phone number:', 
            style: TextStyle(color: null), ),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),

        ),
        CupertinoTextField(
              placeholder: '(555) 555-5555',
              autofocus: true,                            // DO NOT REMOVE, uncomment out in production environment
              clearButtonMode: OverlayVisibilityMode.editing,
              maxLength: 11,
              maxLengthEnforced: true,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              inputFormatters: [WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
              onSubmitted: (phoneNum){
                validatePhone(phoneNum);
                if (this.phoneNumber != null) {
                  openCodePage(context);
                }
              },
              controller: _phoneNumberController,
            ),
        Container(
          child: CupertinoButton(
            color: currentTheme.primaryContrastingColor,
            pressedOpacity: 0.7,
            child: Text('Get Code', style: TextStyle(color: currentTheme.textTheme.textStyle.color),
            ),
            onPressed: (){
              validatePhone(_phoneNumberController.text);
              if (this.phoneNumber != null) {
                openCodePage(context);
              }
            },
          ),
          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```